# Need help with variable transformation in predictive modeling

Tags: predictive-models, modeling, data-transformation, model

Hi Fellow Statisticians,

Could you please help me with variable transformation? I plot the actual vs fitted values at different time points (the red line indicates the diagonal line):

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Apparently the model underestimates the actual values when actual values are high, and overestimates when actual values low. What kind of transformation for the outcome variable would you recommend?

The data is longitudinal, the outcome is positive and continuous, and all the predictors are linear. Using mixed-effects model or simple linear model correcting for clustering within the same individual yields similar prediction result.

Thanks,

Comment: Why do you think a transformation would help?

Comment: I see your point--the systematic under/over-estimation indicates that the right-hand-side of the model may be mis-specified. So variable transformation method won't help much if a model is not correctly specified--did I get it right?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant.